# Getting the exact number of instagram followers

Tags: python-requests, python-re

I am trying to get the exact number of followers of a given instagram account but re is giving me an attribute error.

```
import requests
import re

user = "example"
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + user
r = requests.get(url).text

followers = re.search('"edge_followed_by":{"count":([0-9]+)}',r).group(1)
print(followers)
```

Error:

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 0):

The [re.search documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) says

> Return `None` if no position in the string matches the pattern

If the text does not include your pattern, it will return `None`, which certainly does not have a function `group()`.

You should check if `re.search` returns a match before calling `group` on it.